# DateTime Formatting in MVC4 - DisplayTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im using MVC4 and have a lot of properties on my model that are of type DateTime?.

I thought that I could create a DisplayTemplate (inside Shared\DisplayTemplates) that will format my date as I wish.

However this does not work. It does not output the date in the specified format. Any help would be appreciated..

Model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Date Submitted")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? DateSubmitted { get; set; }'
```

View:

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateSubmitted)
```

Display Template:

```
    DateTime?:
    @model DateTime?
    @string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model)
```

Comment: @Model.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ..though, a nullvalue will blow up in your face

Answer (score 3):

Got it!!!

if you notice that in my property I have

```
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

where as it should be :

```
     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

Doh!!!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try write it as follows:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```

You can learn more info about this from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx)(on example section)

or if you wish to do this in view you can write it as follow in MVC4

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DatePurchase, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")
```

and [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/80n/archive/2012/04/27/apply-a-datetime-format-in-an-asp.net-mvc-textboxfor.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I would like to keep ll the formatting in a template thats why I am dont want to annotate each Date property. If it did blow up at least I would know it was kinda working lol

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DisplayFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```

Comment: As a note - I was using this great link [link](http://doingthedishes.com/2011/07/20/templates-nullable-types-mvc.html)